# Polymorphism vs if and logic

Tags: oop, architecture, polymorphism, logic

```
class Person { 
  private state ="normal" //cripple

  run() { 
    if (this.state === "normal") { 
      console.log("run")
    } else {
      console.log("hobble")
    }
  }
}


//vs

abstract class AttemptRun { 
  abstract run();
}


class NormalRun extends AttemptRun { 
  run() { 
    console.log("run")
  }
}

class CrippleRun extends AttemptRun { 
  run() { 
    console.log("hobble")
  }
}

class Person { 
  protected runAbility: AttemptRun;

  run() { 
    this.runAbility.run()
  }
}
```

Assuming that I understood the concept here is my question.
Why is polymorphism better than if and logic.

Because it seems to me you will still need a factory or another method to set the type of person's ability. So if the logic is not here it's going to be somewhere else.

Why is this repeated some much in books i read, like clean code.
It's listed as a code smell.

I feel like it can make unit test a little bit easier because then you only test the abilities and you don't need to test the actual other class that is using it.

Is that all it has to offer.

An if/else and not you need to write a different class and a factory?
Hardly seems fair?

Perhaps it's more work but in the long run, it will be better.

What are the weaknesses of each case?

Is this something you would do if it's a small class? Basically, I don't know if I understand the concept, and then assuming i do. How practical is it to use.

A wise developer might use it only when they need something specific. I don't know any of the specifics.

Comment: "It depends". Polymorphism (including interfaces) generally allows an 'open set'. This is not always required/desired and there is bit of craftsmanship when deciding which one is 'better' for the given operation. Some questions I routinely ask myself is, 1) "would I _want to inject_ the ability of different [arbitrary] behavior"? 2) "would allowing injection of different behavior enable easier testing"?

Comment: hmm starting to make sense. So use it either for my testing when needed, let's stay a method makes a request to a database, I can swap just that piece out so my unit test can run.

Comment: Yes, testing is often a very good example of when polymorphism (*cough* interfaces / interface contracts *cough*) are very useful. Using interfaces (or pure abstract base classes), which is shown in the example, over class-based subtype polymorphism also generally favors composition.

Comment: hmm, this discussion has been useful. I can think of how I can apply this to unit testing better. especially to avoid IO in my unit test. Thanks

Comment: if you want to write up something cool, i got a vote for you. If anyone else knows of other use cases where this is useful please comment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a couple of things about your simple example that don't demonstrate the benefits of the polymorphic approach.

In your case there's just one if statement (in run), just 2 variations of person, and the behaviour in each case is very similar (they both just log some text).

Consider a larger case where you've got more functionality though. If you add an attemptToDance you'd introduce a new if/else block, if you add other variation of person all your functions need a new if or case in the existing functions. As you add more functionality you end up with many cases in many if/else blocks, and there's no way the compiler can verify for you that you haven't missed one of the person types in of the if cases.

Catching errors with unit tests is great, but choosing a design that makes the error impossible is even better - the compiler never misses things like that, and you know the compiler ran and worked (you hope the unit tests were run successfully - but you're never quite as certain)

If you have an abstract base class defining an interface that all types of person implement, then the compiler will tell you if you fail to implement one of the methods for one of the derived person classes.

In a larger, real case, the implementation of each method on each type of person can and probably will vary more than just outputting different text. if these stay in an if case, all that different functionality ends up in one place, you have code that depends on many things at once, this makes testing and maintenance harder. If the people classes have state such that the methods interact, this complicates things even more, and polymorphism allows you to wrap up that behaviour in a class, without that class needing to concern itself with the other types of person class.

In the simple case the if/else version works, it just doesn't scale very well in many cases.

You may still need an if/else or switch in a factory method somewhere, but one switch that's just responsible for construction is easier to maintain than many switches or if blocks.

Comment: this is a solid answer, from which I will surely benefit in life. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Using polymorphism instead of if-else statements has pros and cons.

#### PROs

1. OOP is a way to improve and promote the **reuse of code**, using if/else statements instead of an abstract class/interface `AttemptRun`with many implementantions you could bump in a situation in which you need to add another class e.g. `Animal` and you'll need to rewrite also the cases in common with class `Person`.
2. Use of polimorphism aids to **maintain the code** by improving its readability.  Very long if-else statement are tiring to read and you have to remember for that is useful, instead a class name directly remind you the function of the specific case.

#### CONs

1. Pro 2 is also a cons: as you said, polymorphism **force you to test  all related classes** that you're using to *inject responsabilities* and *change behaviours*.
2. Polymorphism hits on performance: the correct implementantion of a method is retrieved by compiler by **forwarding**; surely a list of if-else is faster.

Comment: Yes, yes this is making more sense. The context that you use these tools is clearer.

Comment: There is very little performance difference for calling a polymorphic method in modern VM's like the JIT or CLR - in fact, it can be "faster" than (a bunch of) conditional checks! This will obviously vary by implementation and language design as well as the cost of the conditional check(s); consider that even a call to 'Equals' involves a (polymorphic) call in C#/Java.

Comment: The perf argument is a bit thin. "surely a list of if-else is faster", is not really backed by any evidence.