# Nodejs if else alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js

What alternative can I use instead of if condition? I have to write a 10 to 15 of if conditions and inside them we might have other if conditions. So I was wondering if there is any alternative so the code looks better? Something like case switches.

```
  if (sns.Trigger.Namespace == "AWS/ApiGateway") {
    if (dimensionName('ApiId') && dimensionName('Stage')) {
        var sns_DimensionsValue = dimensionValue('ApiId') + '_' + dimensionValue('Stage')
    } else if (dimensionName('ApiName') &&  dimensionName('Stage')) {
        var sns_DimensionsValue =  dimensionValue('ApiName') + '_' +  dimensionValue('Stage') 
    } else if (dimensionName('ApiId')) {
        var sns_DimensionsValue =  dimensionValue('ApiId')    
    } else if (dimensionName('ApiName')) {
        var sns_DimensionsValue =  dimensionValue('ApiName')    
    }
  }   
  
  if (sns.Trigger.Namespace == "AWS/S3") {
      var sns_DimensionsValue = dimensionValue('BucketName') + '_' + dimensionValue('StorageType')
  }  
   
  #
  if AWS/Logs
  if AWS/Lambda
```

Basically I have to check if the JSON data has certain keys vs some other keys in every namespace and then construct a variable. This JSON data is from AWS Cloudwatch event.  dimensionName function queries the JSON data to see if `name` we pass exists in json.. dimensionValue returns the value of the key from JSON data.

Comment: A [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) or if you want to go the [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) route, you'd use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). The `switch` statement link should be self-explanatory. For `if/else` vs polymorphism [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402390/polymorphism-vs-if-and-logic) clarifies it more.

Comment: if your logic genuinely has, say, 5 branches, then its quite reasonable to assume you will have 5 `if/else-if` blocks, `switch` statements would only be altering the syntax in your case, you could, but not sure you are going to gain anything from it

Comment: can you share a example? That would be good.

Comment: What does `dimensionName` do? Is it reasonable to cache its return value rather than calling it multiple times? Similar for `dimensionValue`. Separately, overall what is this code doing? You're asking how to restructure it, but without more information about its source data and goals, it's very hard to restructure it.

Comment: dimensionValue function just returns the value of the named key which we are passing  .

Comment: @John why are checking `dimensionName('ApiName')` and `dimensionName('ApiId')` in every if statement? You can first check if they exist and if they exist then check other values related with them. How about? `if(dN('ApiName')) { if(dN('Stage') {} ...  }`. I think I would be able to help if you give some more data and logic or that json file in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

You can use it like this:

```js
var myVar = myFunc(); // Get some value

switch(myVar) { // Test value possibilities
  case "hello":
    console.log("Say hello"); // Your code for "hello" case here
  break;

  case "Bye":
    console.log("Say bye"); // Your code for "bye" case here
  break;
}
```

Notes:

- Switch is useful to test many variable state
- If you have less than 5 statements, if/else is better
- More than 5, use switch instead of if/else
- By "better" I mean faster and less resource intensive

Edit:

In your case the problem is most certainly the operating logic. If you want to check key presence in JSON, you can maybe iterate over your JSON like this:

```js
Object.keys(myJson).forEach((key) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "key1": // "key1" is in json
      // Code here for "key1" presence
    break;

    // etc...
  }
});
```

Note:

- *Object.keys* documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: and how would this work since the OP's example has around 6 _conditions_ to check.  A switch works well when you have one _condition_ with many cases.  Your answer is simply showing what a `switch` statement is, not how it work in the context of this question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of control flow statements is very small in your case, `if-else` would be fine on its own, or you can use [switch statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

If you want to go for something different, you could use arrays like this

each nested array contains say `[[obj.a, obj.b]] that corresponds to` if (obj.a && obj.b)`, we can loop through this array and then filter out undefined (in the case where the object property doesn't exist)

In the following example the first condition is [obj.a, obj.c], which fails as the property `c` does not exist in `obj` and it will resolve to undefined, and the next condition is [obj.a, obj.b] which passes as both of them are valid in `obj` and will return the values joined by `_`

```js
const obj = {
    a: 'al',
    b: 'bl'
}
const params = [[obj.a, obj.c], [obj.a, obj.b], [obj.b]];

let result;
for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    const x = params[i];
    const value = x.filter(x => x != undefined).length == x.length ? x.join('_') : null;
    if (value) {
        // condition passes, no need to continue the loop
        result = value;
        break;
    }
}

console.log('Final variable value is -> ', result);
```

**Note:** a better solution would be to use `switch`, but this is just one of the possible alternatives to if-else